# Wheel Reinvention Avoidance for Web Rating Feature

Tags: javascript, html

I have a need to implement a rating feature and would like to do it the mouse-over stars way similar to netflix.

What is my best approach? Here are some that come to mind.

- code it up by hand in HTML and
  javascript
- use flash or a java applet
- use [Starbox](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/starbox/) (if you have used Starbox, then feel free to comment on it)
- use another java script library (please specify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [jQuery Star Rating Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/), non-obstrusive, will work even if JavaScript is disabled, its based on a set of radio input boxes, and its very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Starbox is an easy to use way of doing it without reinventing the wheel.

I've done it before using HTML/js but it's not very easy and gets messy.

Flash and Java applets are an overkill, it's not worth the effort (I haven't used any "real" java applets in many years).